# How do i multiply certain elements in a list by 0?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am wondering how i would multiply certain items in a list to 0 to make the list blank again. I need to do this because of a round system I have implemented into my code.

```
totalround1 = [coupleAtotal ,coupleBtotal,coupleCtotal,coupleDtotal,coupleEtotal,coupleFtotal]

totalround1.sort()
print(totalround1)
index0= totalround1[0]
index1= totalround1[1]
index2= totalround1[2]
index3= totalround1[3]
index0 * 0
index1 * 0
index2 * 0
index3 * 0
print(index0,index1,index2,index3)
```

It returns the same values as before, I am wondering how to fix this.

Comment: If you want to assign a list element to zero, just do it.  `totalround[2] = 0`

Comment: Is it that simple? Thanks so much, only just started learning Python - and programming in general!

Comment: The only issue is on the next round, the scores for each of the couple's total's are 0, even when the numbers are inputted. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "the next round"?  Do you mean this code is actually in a loop (which you haven't shown us)?

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually changing the indexes in the second half of your code. You're just multiplying them by zero and not storing them. Do this:

```
totalround[2] = 0
```

instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have noticed though that in the second round, the results don't get replaced with 0.

Comment: Then we're going to need your full code. It's hard to give you a solution when you've only posted a snippet. Also provide full context for what you're trying to do

Comment: You need to include the relevant code with each question. As you stated, my answer does not totally solve your question, so you need to add more code and the context. You can do so by editing your original question